# display clock time from decimal time in matlab

Tags: matlab, time, decimal, clock

I have this code as part of my program to calculate the solar time. But my calculation using decimal time. And now, I need to display the result in clock time.

```
%To calculate solar time
stime = time + (((4*(Lloc-Lsm))+ Et)/60);
disp(['The true solar time is ' num2str(stime),'hr']); %To display the solar time
```

The answer goes like this:

```
The true solar time is 13.0501hr
```

How can I convert the time to clock time (12hr or 24 hr format). i.e the minute should multiply by 60 (0.0501*60min = 3.006) and the time should display as 13:03 or 1:03PM.

Appreciate your help. Thank you.
Regards, -researcher-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to convert to a serial date number and then [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) to build the string with appropriate format:

```
h = 13.0501; %// your computed decimal time
string = datestr(datenum([0 0 0 h 0 0]),14); %// or change "14" for other formats
```

The two formats you specify correspond to formats 13 through 16 in `datestr` (see link to the documentation above). For example, with format 14 the string is

```
>> disp(string)
 1:03:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following

```
my_hour = floor(stime);
my_minute = round(mod(stime, 1) * 60);

disp(['The true solar time is ', num2str(my_hour), ':', num2str(my_minute)]);
```